# C++ Hashing Function in Range

Tags: c++, hash

Given a 32 bit integer A I want to generate a unique integer B for it in the range 1-1023. The same B value should always be generated for the same A value, but each B value must be unique.

I'm using C++ and so far I have:

```
std::hash<std::uint32_t> hasher;
uint32_t num_B = hasher(num_A) % 1023;
```

But I believe this will generate num_B in the range 0-1023, but how do I change the range to 1-1023? I can add 1 and update the max but is there a better method?

Comment: This is impossible. There are more than 1023 different 32 bit integers.

Comment: Also, as written `num_B` will be in the range `0` to `1022`. There's no integer `h` such that `h % 1023 == 1023`. So adding 1 will shift your output from a range of `[0, 1022]` to `[1, 1023]`.

Comment: Yes there are more than 1023 32 bit integers, but for this case I am not using all possible 32 bit integers. Should have clarified.

Comment: @AmandaPunch If there’s at least 38 of them, there’s a better-than-even chance that two will end up hashing to the same number. Even with only 22, there’s still a 20% chance of a collision.

Answer (score -2):

I not sure but test this code:

```
std::hash<std::uint32_t> hasher;
uint32_t num_B = 1+ hasher(num_A) % 1022;
```

Comment: Thanks - this was my solution but wanted to see if there was a better method.

Comment: This isn't actually correct. `num_B` will never be 1023.